# Sum of Three Primes and Vinogradov's Theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

My course instructor told me that every odd number greater than $5$ is sum of three primes. However the following statement is confusing.

But there is a theorem by Vinogradov that states

**There exists some X > 0 such that every integer
n > X can be expressed as a sum of three odd primes.**

So I am confused which of the following is correct. Is it true for all odd numbers greater than $5$ or only for sufficently large odd numbers?

Comment: Vinogradov made the major breakthrough with the partial result. The limit was decreased several times until it was small enough (about $10^{30}$) to be feasible with brute force computer search. Surprisingly this could be done , so the proof is now complete. The result is surprising since it seems not to be significantly easier than the (strong or binary) Goldbach conjecture which is still open.

Comment: In fact, Goldbach is not even known to be true for some infinite family of even numbers  as the powers of $2$ , the factorials or the primorials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vinogradov only proved it for sufficiently large odd numbers, but this result is extended to all odd integers greater than 5 by [Helfgott](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7748).

Comment: Helfgott has proved the result for all odd integers greater than $5$, or it is yet to be verified?